# Struggling with global dictionaries and storing data to call upon later

Tags: python

I am trying to read a file that has a list of tasks. The usernames are displayed on index position 0 on every line of the file. Opening the file, reading the lines and extracting that data I can do. I can get to the point of indexing the data and printing it. What I can't do is create a code to count how many times that user is present in the file. For example if a user is displayed 7 times they must have 7 tasks to complete.

The code I have so far is:

```
user_global = []
def disp_stats():
    with open ("tasks.txt", "r", encoding='cp1252') as tu:
        for lines in tu:
            data_list = lines.strip("\n").split(", ")
            data_list = data_list[0] #this is the data I need to count for how many tasks a user has
            user_global.append(data_list)
            print(user_global)
```

My output for this when I print is not what is as expected. What I wanted to achieve is maybe use something like Counter to count how many times a name appears in a global list. That also didn't work out too well.

Comment: Ignore the file aspect for a sec since it appears to be completely irrelevant to the problem. If you had a list that looked like this: `[1, 2, 3, 2, 6, 2, 1, 9]`, would you know how to count occurrences?

Comment: if name not in user_dict:
            user_dict[name] = 1
        else: 
            user_dict[name] += 1

Comment: Have you tried using code like that? What was the problem?

Comment: The data is stored into the global dictionary. How then can I pull that data apart to display it better?
i.e : John has 4 tasks

Comment: `user_dict['John']`.

Comment: Just to make sure: you understand that `user_global = []` **does not** create a dict (but instead a list), right?

Comment: Ok that works really well. Now for instance if I do not know the users who are in the global dictionary and I want to print those. Can I include something like wildcards...

Comment: Just print the whole dictionary so see what's in the dictionary. Or iterate it using a `for` like you would any other structure (although you may want to iterate `user_dict.items()` to get all key/value pairs).